# Android - Is it possible to eavesdrop the bundle from a remote service to another activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Assume the remote service use onHandleIntent to handle the message, and its activity use onResultReceiver to receive it. Is there any way for an activity in other package to fake as real activity and receive the message? Thanks.

Comment: Using endorsed mechanisms?  No.  But if the target is in the same process, or at least one belonging to the same UID, then technically it is possible if you want to spend enough time figuring out the details of how it works behind the scenes *in a particular implementation*

Comment: I see. I have another question: is it possible to get the context or the referenced service object in the activity which binds the service? @ChrisStratton